# Django: Referencing the pk in a multi form view

Tags: django, image, file-upload, django-forms, django-views

I have a view with two forms. I am trying to reference the uploaded image's pk in the same form. How do i do that?

```
form1 = ImageForm(request.FILES, request.POST)
form2= SongForm(request.POST or None)
if form2.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
    image = form1.save(commit=False)
    image.save()
    save_file(request.FILES['image'])
    song = form2.save(commit=False)
    song.image = the uploaded image's pk???
    song.save()
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call `image.save()` image should get a pk, and therefore, you should be able to reference it with `image.pk`.